# Diagnosing boot time problem

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, systemd, boot-time

I never thought much about my laptop's boot time but I now heard people complain about boot times of 30 s. I think that's about what my laptop needs, too, maybe even longer, and my laptop is better or equal to those other laptops in every way I can think of (apart from battery life). My laptop currently is busy and will be busy for a few more hours, but afterwards, I'll reboot it and see how long it takes.

I heard that you should look for leaps in the output of `$ dmesg`. And there really is a leap of 13.8 s in [my output of it](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23989814/).

The [output of `$ systemd-analyze blame`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23989909/) starts off with 2 lines denoting very long times:

```
 20.002s rc-local.service
  5.751s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

What's causing the long boot time and how can it be fixed?

Comment: What is inside `/etc/rc.local`?

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23990031/ Oh, right. I put those 2 lines in there to have my speakers turned off when they aren't in use so they won't whoosh when not playing sound. Does that actually cause a delay or only cause a big number to be shown by `systemd-analyze blame`? If you don't know, that's fine, of course. I'll find out when I can reboot my laptop.

Comment: @Thomas Wow, that really made a huge difference! I shut my laptop down, got a stopwatch out, and measured the time from pressing the power button to the login screen appearing and the login screen sound playing. With the 2 lines I added to `/etc/rc.local` active, I measured 30.45 s. With them having been commented out, I only measured 17.67 s. The first line of `systemd-analyze blame`'s output now is the network manager one and the biggest gap in the output of `dmesg` is of 4 s: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23990400/ I will definitely check whether I can run the speaker thing asynchronously.

Comment: It runs asynchronously and I measured 17.75 s when running it that way! :) Anything else which can easily be improved?